# Page freeze and $resource

Tags: angularjs

So when my page loads, angular calls a service to populate three arrays. This service uses $resource to fetch data (JSON) from the backend. The problem is, while the data is loading the whole page freezes for a second and the spinners are static. My understanding is that $resource and $http are all asynchronous and the page shouldn't freeze when they're active. I've tried the promise pattern approach suggested by [this](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angularjs-creating-service-with-http.html) article but without luck. Any advice?
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** added the code

```
mobiModule.factory('DataSrv', function($q, $http) {
    return {
        getData: function(url) {
            var defered = $q.defer();

            //make the call
            $http.get(url).success(function(data){
                console.dir(data);
                defered.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(){
                console.log('HTTP error');
                defered.reject();
            });

            return defered.promise;
        }
    }
});   



$scope.phones = Phones.query(); //using $resource('phones.json')
```

or

```
$scope.phones = DataSrv.getData('phones.json'); //using the service defined above
```

Comment: How much data are you retrieving?  Also, have you tried narrowing down the problem with a javascript profiler, like Chrome Dev Tools, or perhaps Batarang (an angularJS plugin for Chrome) https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang

Comment: I'm paginating the data in Laravel and it sends an array of 8 phones with their specs to Angular. I've just checked the performance data in Batarang and got the following:

 h | 88.4% | 1608ms, 

function (a){var e,f,h=a.$eval(j), | 9.11% | 165.8ms

Comment: Nothing seems wrong here. Does the problem persist when you assign some static phones array to your `phones` var?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. Every phone has its input form which contains a list of 460 cities. So that's 460 additional models on every phone. I guess I'll load the cities on demand, when the input form is activated. Thanks for taking the time to reply!